# Expanders in Grid

Tags: wpf, layout

This is going to be straight forward no doubt, but for what ever reason, my mind is drawing a blank on it.

I've got a small, non-resizeable window (325x450) which has 3 Expanders in it, stacked vertically. Each Expander contains an ItemsControl that can potentially have a lot of items in and therefore need to scroll.

What I can't seem to get right is how to layout the Expanders so that they expand to fill any space that is available without pushing other elements off the screen. I can sort of achieve what I'm after by using a Grid and putting each expander in a row with a * height, but this means they are always taking up 1/3 of the window each which defeats the point of the Expander :)

Crappy diagram of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this would work, but you might try setting a MaxHeight for each Grid RowDefinition, then clear the MaxHeight whenever the expander in that Row is expanded.  Unfortunately MaxHeight is not a Dependency Property, so this would probably require some code-behind or an attached Behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't mind a little code-behind, you could probably hook into the `Expanded`/`Collapsed` events, find the parent `Grid`, get the `RowDefinition` for the expander, and set the value equal to `*` if its expanded, or `Auto` if not.

For example,

```
Expander ex = sender as Expander;
Grid parent = FindAncestor<Grid>(ex);
int rowIndex = Grid.GetRow(ex);

if (parent.RowDefinitions.Count > rowIndex && rowIndex >= 0)
    parent.RowDefinitions[rowIndex].Height = 
        (ex.IsExpanded ? new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) : GridLength.Auto);
```

And the `FindAncestor` method is defined as this:

```
public static T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject current)
where T : DependencyObject
{
    // Need this call to avoid returning current object if it is the 
    // same type as parent we are looking for
    current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);

    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current is T)
        {
            return (T)current;
        }
        current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
    };
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that'll do it! The events are Expanded/Collapsed btw :) Thanks!

Comment: @Tom I just looked them up, but you beat me to it :)

Comment: @Tom lol and thanks for the edit, I never noticed my WPF library had the wrong spelling of Ancestor this whole time

Comment: No probs. I probably wouldn't have noticed it if the complier didn't flag it up! My code is no doubt full of spelling mistakes or a mish-mash of UK/US spellings :)

Answer (score 11):

This requirement is a little unusal because the you want the state of the `Children` in the `Grid` to decide the `Height` of the `RowDefinition` they are in.
*I really like the layout idea though and I can't believe I never had a similar requirement myself.. :)*

For a reusable solution I would use an Attached Behavior for the `Grid`.
The behavior will subscribe to the Attached Events `Expander.Expanded` and `Expander.Collapsed` and in the event handlers, get the right `RowDefinition` from `Grid.GetRow` and update the `Height` accordingly. It works like this

```
<Grid ex:GridExpanderSizeBehavior.SizeRowsToExpanderState="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Expander Grid.Row="0" ... />
    <Expander Grid.Row="1" ... />
    <Expander Grid.Row="2" ... />
    <!-- ... -->
</Grid>
```

And here is **GridExpanderSizeBehavior**

```
public class GridExpanderSizeBehavior
{
    public static DependencyProperty SizeRowsToExpanderStateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SizeRowsToExpanderState",
                                            typeof(bool),
                                            typeof(GridExpanderSizeBehavior),
                                            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, SizeRowsToExpanderStateChanged));
    public static void SetSizeRowsToExpanderState(Grid grid, bool value)
    {
        grid.SetValue(SizeRowsToExpanderStateProperty, value);
    }
    private static void SizeRowsToExpanderStateChanged(object target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid grid = target as Grid;
        if (grid != null)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
            {
                grid.AddHandler(Expander.ExpandedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Expander_Expanded));
                grid.AddHandler(Expander.CollapsedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Expander_Collapsed));
            }
            else if ((bool)e.OldValue == true)
            {
                grid.RemoveHandler(Expander.ExpandedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Expander_Expanded));
                grid.RemoveHandler(Expander.CollapsedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Expander_Collapsed));
            }
        }
    }
    private static void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid grid = sender as Grid;
        Expander expander = e.OriginalSource as Expander;
        int row = Grid.GetRow(expander);
        if (row <= grid.RowDefinitions.Count)
        {
            grid.RowDefinitions[row].Height = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star); 
        }
    }
    private static void Expander_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid grid = sender as Grid;
        Expander expander = e.OriginalSource as Expander;
        int row = Grid.GetRow(expander);
        if (row <= grid.RowDefinitions.Count)
        {
            grid.RowDefinitions[row].Height = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Auto);
        }
    }
}
```